# Assembly language simple program

Tags: assembly

I have to write a simple program in assembly language for the H8S. The user enters 50 uint16 numbers, and after each number the program should sort all entered numbers and print them out. How can I implement something like Array and work with it?

```
        .text
        .global _start

_start:
        mov.l   #stck,ER7           
        xor.l   ER6,ER6             

begin:
         inc.l  #1,ER6                                      
        mov.w   #PUTS,R0            
        mov.l   #par_o,ER1          
        jsr     @syscall

        mov.w   #GETS,R0            
        mov.l   #par_i,ER1          
        jsr     @syscall

        jsr     @insert
        jsr     @sort
        jsr     @write

        cmp.l   #50,ER6
        bcs     begin
        jmp     @end


insert:
        rts


sort:   
        rts

write:  
        rts


end:    


        jmp @end
```

Comment: use indirect adressing opcodes for an array

Answer (score 0):

suppose you are on MASM, you can use the operator "DUP"
like in

```
smallarray dword 10 DUP (?)
```

this line will define an array with 10 members of double words with unknown initial values

for accessing it's members you can use indirect access , something like

```
mov eax, [smallarray]    ;first member
mov eax, [smallarray+4]  ;second member
mov eax, [smallarray+8]  ;third member
mov eax, [smallarray+12] ;fourth member
mov eax, [smallarray+16] ;fifth member
;....... we used 4 bytes because the members are dword (4 bytes long)
```

Comment: unfortunately i have to use GCC